# Insert price to the pivot table

Tags: php, sql, arrays, laravel

I am trying to insert data to a pivot table order_serrvice using arrays
I follow this code: https://blog.quickadminpanel.com/master-detail-form-in-laravel-jquery-create-order-with-products/

the column qty and service was inserted properly but the price does not, I dont know why?

order_service table:

```
  Schema::create('order_service', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreignId('service_id');
            $table->foreignId('order_id');
            $table->float('price')->default(0);
            $table->integer('qty')->default(0);

            $table->primary(['service_id','order_id']);
```

OrderController:

```
 $services = $request->input('services', []);
        $quantities = $request->input('qty', []);
        $price=$request->input('price', []);
        for ($service=0; $service < count($services); $service++) {
            if ($services[$service] != '') {
                $order->services()->attach($services[$service], ['qty' => $quantities[$service]], ['price' => $price[$service]]);

            }
```

with dd($request):

```
 "services" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "3"
        1 => "2"
      ]
      "qty" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "861"
        1 => "748"
      ]
      "price" => array:2 [▼
        0 => "20"
        1 => "40"
```

dd($price[$service])

```
"20"
```

Data base outbut

```
| order_id |  service_id    |price | qty|
| -------- | -------------- |______|____|
| 2074     | 2              |0.00  |748 |
| 2074     | 3              |0.00  |861 |
```

Can any one help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you are misusing the `attach()` method:

```php
$order->services()->attach(
    $services[$service], 
    ['qty' => $quantities[$service]], 
    ['price' => $price[$service]]  // something wrong with your arrays here, it only needs one in the second argument
);
```

The `attach()` method should be used like this:

```php
$order->services()->attach(
    $services[$service], [
        'qty' => $quantities[$service], 
        'price' => $price[$service] 
    ]
);
```

The second parameter is an array with all additional pivot values.

Answer (score 1):

Hello try with this code by attach value in single array

$order->services()->attach($services[$service], ['qty' => $quantities[$service], 'price' => $price[$service]]);